# Memory leak on CreateErrorInfo when analyze from debugdiag?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, debugdiag

I am analyzing a memory dump created by debugdiag. It shows CreateErrorinfo method call which leads to memory leak like below,

I am using proper map files for mydll and myanotherdll both. What is the meaning of CreateErrorInfo ? how it's leading to memory leak?

Function   Source   Destination 
mfc90u!operator new+33
mfc90u!CPlex::Create+1f      mfc90u!operator new 
kernel32!TlsSetValueStub
kernel32!TlsSetValueStub
**MYANOTHERDLL**!**CreateErrorInfo**+188e2
**MYDLL!MyClas::OnTimer+a3   ......\myfile.cpp @ 4639**
**MYDLL!CMainFrame::OnTimer+71    ......\mainfrm.cpp @ 1246**
mfc90u!CWnd::OnWndMsg+407
mfc90u!AfxCallWndProc+a3
user32!MDIClientWndProcW
mfc90u!__sse2_available_init+657b
mfc90u!CWnd::WindowProc+24
mfc90u!AfxCallWndProc+a3
mfc90u!AfxWndProc+37      mfc90u!AfxCallWndProc 
mfc90u!AfxWndProcBase+56      mfc90u!AfxWndProc 
mfc90u!AfxWndProcBase

Comment: Show us the code of MyClas::OnTimer. Maybe you don't free the interface pointer you get.

Answer (score 2):

Is this related to not releasing an interface? Interface from CreatorErroInfo must be released by client:

```
ICreateErrorInfo* pErrorInfo = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = ::CreateErrorInfo(&pErrorInfo);

if (pErrorInfo)
{
   pErrorInfo->Release();
}
```

Even better to use ATL's smart pointers:

```
CComPtr<ICreateErrorInfo> ptrErrorInfo;
HRESULT hr = ::CreateErrorInfo(&ptrErrorInfo);

if (ptrErrorInfo)
{
   //no release necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateErrorInfo creates an instance of a generic error object.

This function returns a pointer to a generic error object, which you can use with QueryInterface on ICreateErrorInfo to set its contents. I believe you should check the state of ICreateErrorInfo pointer for more details in your code.