# Which is proper handling of IErrorInfo release

Tags: c++, com, visual-c++-6

This is likely basic but it's been a long while since I used this.  I have seen examples like each of the following:

```
IErrorInfo *pError;
HRESULT hrError = ::GetErrorInfo(NULL, &pError);
//more code here            
if (SUCCEEDED(hrError) && pError) {
    //more code here            
    pError->Release();
}
```

and then elsewhere

```
IErrorInfo *pError;
HRESULT hrError = ::GetErrorInfo(NULL, &pError);
//more code here            
if (SUCCEEDED(hrError) && pError) {
    //more code here            
}
pError->Release();
```

Which of these is the proper way to use the `Release()` here?  Does it matter; and if so why?

Comment: They are both wrong.  This kind of "don't tell me I have a null pointer bug" coding style is pervasive and doesn't do anything but create "it doesn't work" bug reports.  You can't avoid eventually finding the bug in the 2nd snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant perhaps this the unstated part of what bothered me about the first example, now what would be the better way to do that?

Comment: Just delete ` && pError`

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212380/memory-leak-on-createerrorinfo-when-analyze-from-debugdiag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first usage is correct, although in the "more code here" you must be careful not to throw an exception.

It would be better to use a smart pointer instead of `IErrorInfo *`, which will automatically call `Release()` when going out of scope. Then your code will not leak in the case of the "more code here" throwing an exception.

The second one is wrong, because if `pError` is null or indeterminate, then dereferencing it causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is what I was thinking myself but as I indicated I have not been doing c++ COM stuff for a while...